# "Impossible to engage a segment in the current layer"

Tags: qgis, polygon

How can I fix this ? My problem is the red "x".

[this is the screen http://imageshack.com/a/img540/8232/o6zUnB.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img540/8232/o6zUnB.png)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS SE.  Can you be more specific with your problem?  Please edit your question to include more details about what we are looking at and what you are trying to do.

Comment: How can i delete that x? This is my problem...

Comment: Welcome! In order to help solve your problem, we need a little more information. What are you specifically trying to accomplish? What tools are you using? What, if any, error messages do you receive? What are your results and why are they not as expected?

Comment: I can't select "x" with the "vertex tool"

Comment: The error message is "impossible to engage a segment in the current layer"

Comment: I'm using Q-Gis 2.6.1

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120728/node-tool-could-not-snap-to-a-segment-on-the-current-layer-message

Comment: I already set: topological editing,anchor at intersections,avoids intersections. Sorry for my english, i'm using an italian q-gis version.

Comment: I can see only a raster layer. For topologocal editing, you would have a vector layer.