# Deleting lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features

I have a layer with several shapes and from here I want to delete the lines. I tryed Toggle editing and Select features by polygon but when closing the polygon, it dissapears. Also I tried to delete all the nodes that I don't want by selecting them with the Node Tool buton, but nothing happened. What do you suggest me to do?

This is my example: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are enabling the edits on the correct layer? Did you try refreshing it? sometimes residual lines are shown for a bit but they don't remain there.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Yes, I am on the correct layer. I also tried to close and reopen the project. I added a picture above, so that you can see that the edditing is on.

Comment: I have checked now, and apparently I can't delete the nodes from the Node Tool in case the shape has less than 4 nodes.

Comment: How are you deleting the features? Pressing the `Del` key on the keyboard or through the toolbar _Edit > Delete Selected_?

Comment: is the layer one feature or multipart? if it's a multipart, try using the delete part in the advanced digitizing toolbar

Comment: What do you mean by "When closing the polygon it disappears"? what polygon are you talking about exactly?

Comment: The delete selected buton is freezed, so I am deleting with Del buton. It is one feature, not a multipart one. I reffered that when I am trying select features by polygon so that I can delete few features, it selects the whole layer, not just what is within the polygon. I guess this happens because the layer contains just one feature.

Comment: You only have the one feature in your layer and you are trying to delete nodes within that feature?

Comment: Yes. Everything that you can see from the above pictures are one feature in the layer. But I want to delete the lines, so that I can have just the polygons left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shapefile contains a *multipart* single feature as mentioned by @HDunn. In order to delete separate polygons, you will need to convert this to *singleparts* by using the **Multipart to Singleparts** tool:

*Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to Singleparts*.

I ran this and saved the output as *"Free space v2.shp"*. Now you can edit and delete those pesky polygons!

[image: Multipart layer]

[image: Multipart layer edited]

I noticed there's quite a few of those *dangles* in your layer. A good method may be to use GRASS's **v.clean** tool with the **rmdangle** option to remove them automatically. You can access this from:

*Processing Toolbox > GRASS commands > Vector (v.*) > v.clean*

I used the following parameters (note the fairly high threshold):

[image: v.clean]

Before being cleaned:

[image: Before cleaned]

After being cleaned:

[image: After cleaned]

If there are any more polygons you don't want, you can remove them manually as there should be a lot less of them now.

Comment: You may want to lower the threshold from `100` as it does cut out a number of polygons which look as though they should be kept.

Answer (score 5):

First Make sure that you have enabled editing on the correct layer. Then use the `Node Tool` to select the nodes you want to delete (right click and drag to create a rectangle and select the nodes)
[image]
Press `delete` and you are done, don't forget to save your edits.
[image]

Comment: Node tool: could not snap to a segment on the current layer.  This is the answer that I am receving when I am following your steps. Just this layer is turned on, so then for sure is the right one that I am using for editing.

Comment: Take a look at this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120728/node-tool-could-not-snap-to-a-segment-on-the-current-layer-message

Comment: It's probably because your snapping tolerance is set as 0.

Comment: I have changed it. Even if I select several nodes, they don't get deleted. I can delete the nodes of a line only until I reach at 3 nodes, and from there it does not allow me to do anything else.

Comment: So you can delete 3 nodes in every line, or in total 3 nodes before it stops letting you do anything?

Comment: I can delete as many nodes as I want but when a segment has just 3 nodes, I can't delete any more. That is why I also can't delete lines that have from the begining just 2 nodes. And the same goes for nodes that are just one point.

Comment: The `node tool` won't allow you to completely delete features, some nodes must remain for the node tool to be active on the feature, to do that just select the feature and delete (can use select feature by rectangle), I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36120/discussion-between-adela-ioana-moldovan-and-hasan-mustafa).

Comment: @Adela-IoanaMoldovan - You could upload your data on a public server so that others could test it. This does seem like a weird issue.

Comment: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/31bd60c7a689e5749cf6c97bc4b1ba0620160223133930/4b9c5b8c1582eb1a799a4f8569e0cf8520160223133930/199dd2  This is the link with my shapefile. From here I would like to have just the closed polygons, so I want to delete the lines and points.