# Cannot delete lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have uploaded bunch of gpx files into QGIS, but some of them has noise. This is what I have:

[image]
I tried that: [Deleting lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181852/deleting-lines-in-qgis) but no success.

What I want, is to delete selected:

[image]

but for some reason, delete selected option is grayed out. I also saved layer to shp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least in your image above, you didn't use the "Selection" tool, but the "Inspection":

[image: Left: Inspection, Right: Selection]

Could it be that easy?

Comment: Also, some data types can't be edited using QGIS.

Comment: @Erik, Thank you, also works

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of how to do it on any kind of layer. 
Enable editing, then select vertex tool on current layer, right mouse button click on the line, then the coordinates will appear on the left side, and then simply press del on keyboard.

[image]

Thank you guys.