# QGIS cannot snap

Tags: snapping, qgis-2.8

I am using QGIS 2.8.1 in Linuxmint 17. When I set the snap option, the message box is like this which is different from the pictures I found on the Internet. [image]

After I setting this and reload QGIS, the snapping function is still unavailable and it shows a warning like this. [image] So I am wondering how I can solve this problem.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this error on win 10 & qgis 2.14.3 with no successes. I suggest you try the followings:  (a) follow [this thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120728/node-tool-could-not-snap-to-a-segment-on-the-current-layer-message); (b) upgrade qgis; (c) try a [virtual box](http://www.howtogeek.com/133515/4-ways-to-run-windows-software-on-linux/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the "old" look if you change the `All Layer` combo box to `Advanced`.

I suggest to use 10 Pixels, and only to the vertex. The same should be set in `Options -> Digitizing`, snapping section, search radius.

BTW updating to QGIS 2.14.4 or 2.16 is not a bad idea. I'm not sure what bugs were fixed after 2.8.1 was released.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact the problem happens when I use the `advanced digitizing` plugin, though I changed to `advanced` this plugin still cannot do snapping. I think I should update it.